# Can you see your circles' +1s in your Google+ Stream?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-1

I know you can view your friends' (circles') various +1s by going to their profile page and clicking the +1 tab.

I don't want to check and recheck each friend's +1, with each behind 4 clicks to get there, every day. And then have to remember which I've seen and which I haven't.

Is there a way to see those +1s in your main Google+ Stream alongside posts at the Google+ home page? Or will the Stream only ever show full Posts?

If there is not a Google-supplied version, are there any Chrome (or other browser) add-ons/extensions that have a feature to inject the +1s in the correct places in your Stream?

Comment: Am I asking the wrong question? Or is there another good way to see your friends' +1 posts in an efficient, combined, linear method?

Answer (score 1):

There does not seem to be any available add-on/extension that accomplishes this.